# Using swftools on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, image-processing, heroku, flash

I have a legacy rails 2.3.14 app that I'm trying to get running on heroku. I'm using delayed job to run a background processto connvert pdfs into .swf files. Here is the command that I'm using to process . I can get it running locally. Here is the command I'm using in the app.

```
system <<-COMMAND
pdf2swf --pages=#{page_numbers} #{@pdf_path} -o #{swf_file_path}

COMMAND
```

When I try to run it on heroku, I get this error message

```
sh: pdf2swf: not found
```

After spending time on google and searching stack overflow and heroku docs, I'm a lost on what to do next. Is there a way to install swftools on heroku? I'm open to using other options if there is a way to convert pdfs to swfs. Thank you

### Edit

Reto's solution  worked but swftools needed some other dependencies was buggy etc. I tried to go through the dependencies and used some different files in the Aptfile. Mine now looks like the below. I'll try to clean this up at some point.

```
http://launchpadlibrarian.net/26103422/gsfonts_8.11%2Burwcyr1.0.7~pre44-4_all.deb
xpdf
http://launchpadlibrarian.net/14367756/libart-2.0-2_2.3.20-2_amd64.deb
http://launchpadlibrarian.net/62074298/libc6_2.10.1-0ubuntu19_amd64.deb
http://launchpadlibrarian.net/24108389/libfontconfig1_2.6.0-1ubuntu12_amd64.deb
http://launchpadlibrarian.net/58630613/libfreetype6_2.3.9-5ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb

=http://launchpadlibrarian.net/37680616/libgcc1_4.4.1-4ubuntu9_amd64.deb
http://launchpadlibrarian.net/19368718/libgif4_4.1.6-6_amd64.deb

http://launchpadlibrarian.net/26605143/libjpeg62_6b-14build1_amd64.deb

http://launchpadlibrarian.net/37680642/libstdc%2B%2B6_4.4.1-4ubuntu9_amd64.deb

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zlib/1:1.2.3.3.dfsg-13ubuntu3
http://launchpadlibrarian.net/27270374/swftools_0.9.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb

http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/x/xpdf/xpdf_3.03-17.debian.tar.xz
```

Comment: What OS are you using locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the `swftools` package on Ubuntu 14.04 (what heroku is running) doesn't contain `pdf2swf` anymore. So you have to install an older version (0.8.1):

Use [heroku-buildpack-multi](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi/) to use the https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt and install swftools and dependencies:

```
$ heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
```

From here you will need to create a `.buildpacks` file which contains (in order) the buildpacks you wish to run when you deploy:

```
$ cat .buildpacks
https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby
```

Then you need to create a `Aptfile` file which contains this packages:

```
$ cat Aptfile
libart-2.0-2
libjpeg62
libt1-5
http://launchpadlibrarian.net/11111323/swftools_0.8.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Then you can use `pdf2swf`.

```
$ heroku run pdf2swf --version
Running `./pdf2swf --version` attached to terminal... up, run.5153
pdf2swf - part of swftools 0.8.1
```

Comment: This worked, I just needed to change the Aptfile to allow it to actually process pdfs.